# Copy parquet to Redshift got error 1216 Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x15 found at location 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a mysql table

```
create table orderitems
(
    id char(36) collate utf8_bin not null
        primary key,
    store_id char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
    ref_type int not null,
    ref_id char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
    store_product_id char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
    product_id char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
    product_name varchar(50) null,
    main_image varchar(200) null,
    price int not null,
    count int not null,
    is_gift tinyint(1) not null,
);
```

My colleague used sqoop dump this table into multiple parquet files under a s3 path. I need load those files into redshift.

#### First

I tried above mysql table DDL and found that 
`collate`, `utf8_bin` , `null`,`not null` and `tinyint` not support in redshift.
So I use below to create orderitems table in redshift

```
create table orderitems
(
    id char(36),
    store_id char(36),
    ref_type int,
    ref_id char(36),
    store_product_id char(36),
    product_id char(36),
    product_name varchar(50),
    main_image varchar(200),
    price int,
    count int,
    is_gift SMALLINT,
);
```

#### Then

Import data by :

```
COPY orderitems from 's3://xxxx/arch/M/orderitems/' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxx'
```

But got error

```
[XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Load into table 'orderitems' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.;
```

Check the `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` table and found

```
1216    Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x15 found at location 4
```

I have searched around but nothing found. Could anyone tell me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving the format portions of the copy command as default.

Per [Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#r_COPY-syntax-overview-optional-parameters):

> By default, the COPY command expects the source data to be in
>   character-delimited UTF-8 text files. The default delimiter is a pipe
>   character ( | ).

Character delimited files use newlines to differentiate each record which explains the error message you are getting.

Since Parquet is a unique format with it's own rules, you have to give Redshift more information about the type of file you are attempting to load.

I.E.:

```
COPY orderitems from 's3://xxxx/arch/M/orderitems/'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxx' 
FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

Comment: In Redshift 1.0.5463 .Adding  `FORMAT AS PARQUET` would get `[0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: COPY from PARQUET format is not supported` ; Since I have seen a doc said redshift support parquet by default in somewhere. If it does not support parquet in this version, that would be very disappoint.

Comment: Used parquet since 2017 with redshift. For sure your redshift version knows parquet. You need to add `Format as parquet` . Try to convert de file to csv, reduce the number of columns, split de fole until you find the error.